# Database in android?

Tags: android, database, auto-increment

I want to know how it is better to work with databases in android: with

```
_id integer primary key autoincrement
```

or without `autoincrement`?

In my app I have 2 tables, one with lists,and one with products. If I delete a list and I don't use `autoincrement` the new list I will do will have the products of the lists I deleted.

Thats mean that if I don't use `autoincrement` when I delete a list from a table, I have to delete its product too. So, which method is better?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you have a field named _id, it will automatically be autoincremented in sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLIte db table always has autoincrement field rowid.
You can refer docs:
[ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yout lists should have a auto-incremented `id`-field, so you can use it for things like showing it in a `ListActivity` (which uses the `_id`-field for the `onClick`-method).

When you delete your whole list, it's entry's are no longer needed (otherwise you wouldn't delete the whole list), so you'll want to delete them, too. If the Entry's also have the list's ID (from the list they belong to), you can delete all of them with one query, too.